# What is wrong with this attempt to extend a Scala class that contains a vararg parameter

Tags: scala, extends, variadic-functions

```
class U(successors:U*) {}
class V(successors:U*) extends U(successors) {}
```

The second line doesn't compile. Type mismatch on the second occurrence of successors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`U*` is converted to `Seq[U]`. Use,

```
class V(successors: U*) extends U(successors:_*) {}
```